# Calculate time shift between two signals and shifting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a temperature sensor and a strain sensor, I would like to calculate the time delay between the two sensors.

```
def process_data_time_delay(temperature, strain, normal_data):
    from scipy import signal

    T1 = temperature['T1'].tolist()
    S1 = strain[0]
    time = normal_data['TIMESTAMP'].tolist()

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(time, T1, 'r')
    plt.plot(time, S1, 'b')

    shift = (np.argmax(signal.correlate(T1, S1)))
    fig  = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(time, T1 - shift)
    plt.show()
```

I have a strange and strange output graph.

[image]

Here is a sample data

https://pastebin.com/eEd6MTL0

According to the excellent answer I have modified the code to calculate the time delay between the two signals.

```
def process_data_time_delay(temperature, strain, df):
    from scipy import signal

    # normalization before ACF
    def normalize(data):
        return (data - np.mean(data, axis=0).reshape((1, -11))) / (np.std(data, axis=0).reshape((1, -1)))

    # select subset of columns, seems relevant as a group
    SCOLS = ['T1', 'W_A1']

    # just to see the data
    f = plt.figure()
    ax = f.add_subplot(111)
    df[SCOLS[:2]].iloc[::10].plot(ax=ax)
    ax.set_title('Raw data')

    # normalization
    normalized = normalize(df[SCOLS].values)
    f = plt.figure()
    ax = f.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(np.arange(normalized.shape[0]), normalized[:, 0], label='TW_A1')
    ax.plot(np.arange(normalized.shape[0]), normalized[:, 1], label='W_A1')
    ax.set_title('Normalized')

    # ACF between two components
    x1x2 = np.correlate(normalized[:, 0], normalized[:, 1], 'full')

    # see the results
    f = plt.figure()
    ax = f.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x1x2)
    ax.set_title('ACF')
    df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'])
    peaks_indices = signal.find_peaks_cwt(np.array(x1x2), np.arange(1, len(x1x2)))
    print(peaks_indices)
    delta_index = np.argmax(peaks_indices);
    delta_time = df['TIMESTAMP'][delta_index] - df['TIMESTAMP'][0]
    # assuming timestamps is a datetime64 numpy array that can be easily obtained from pandas;
    shifted_signal = x1x2[delta_time:]

    f = plt.figure()
    ax = f.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(shifted_signal)

    # mainloop
    plt.show()

    return x1x2
```

Comment: can you show some sample data? How does your input look like?

Comment: here is a sample data http://www.mediafire.com/file/r7dg7i9dacvpl2j/curve_fitting_ahmed.xlsx/file

Comment: @Dschoni I think the problem is the time ( time stamp ) is in data time format ?

Comment: `T1` is a list. I am surprised how is `T1 - shift` working for you

Comment: @Bazingaa is it necessary that time should be in utc format ? How would I do shifting for T1 ?

Comment: please put everything needed to understand the question inside the question. Post one or two lines from your dataset into the question. I cannot access the above link.

Comment: @Dschoni I have put some sample test data, between T(temperature) and W(strain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not about python, it is about signal processing.
There are many techniques and issues around phase estimation. For instance, in periodic signals (such as Cosine or a square wave) there are infinite correct answers since the real phase shift + integer times of the period will give the same result. On the other hand, even in non-periodic signals, such as one impulse, noise may effect the phase detection, in some cases more than others. This field is broad and the answer strongly depend on what you want to achieve and the data quality.

Having said that, here is my output from your data (two components) using ACF as a first step for the inspection, I don't see a problem with it:

**EDIT:**
Added some corrections and changed signals to the real targets.

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

Regarding phase shift estimation, there are many ways to do so. Please research the traditional literature for answers and explore techniques oriented for your type of data. My suggestions:

1. First peak of ACF can be a good answer.
2. Projection on sine waves (partial Fourier series) and adjusting the phase at the largest coefficients.
3. Phase detection based on fitting the same models and inspection of parameters (can be done automatic, depends on the model).
4. Using an envelope detector (for this data) and detecting the phases between the two upper lines and the two bottom lines. You'll get two estimations, you can take the average.
5. Use more preprocessing - trend and seasonality decomposition, and take the seasonality component for inspecting the phase.

There are many ways, these just pop up right away. I'm sure that by playing with it a little you can find that suits your data in a reasonable computation time so it will be applicable for your product.

Good luck!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the code:

```
# just some imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

# load data
df = pd.read_csv('c:\\Temp\\curve_fitting_ahmed.csv')

# normalization before ACF
def normalize(data):
    return (data - np.mean(data, axis=0).reshape((1, -11))) / (np.std(data, axis=0).reshape((1, -1)))


# select subset of columns, seems relevant as a group
SCOLS = ['TW_A1','W_A1']

# just to see the data
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
df[SCOLS[:2]].iloc[::10].plot(ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Raw data')

# normalization
normalized = normalize(df[SCOLS].values)
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.arange(normalized.shape[0]),normalized[:,0], label='TW_A1')
ax.plot(np.arange(normalized.shape[0]),normalized[:,1], label='W_A1')
ax.set_title('Normalized')

# ACF between two components
x1x2 = np.correlate(normalized[:, 0], normalized[:, 1], 'full')

# see the results
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x1x2)
ax.set_title('ACF')

# mainloop
plt.show()
```

Comment: B.T.W without filtering and restricting the shift length, you can easily get a wrong maxima. see the tail of the ACF.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but You did the time shift between TW_1 and TW_2 which are two temperature sensors, what I need is TW_1 with W_A1, and also I need the resultant shifted signal from the correlation of TW_1 with W_A1

Comment: For example I correlate TW_1 with W_A1, then I get a result signal with time shift, then I want to get the result signal of the correlation with time shift.

Comment: Amazing, Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there a difference, If I use the Shifted Strain or the Shifted temperature ?

Comment: The answer is now improved. The shifting and parameter estimation - please see the beginning of the answer, I suspect you'll need to work a little harder to extract the exact shift. Although the peak is at large shift, I suspect it is incorrect. My guess it is the first peak. Hope you'll find my comments well and have good luck with your project!

Comment: is the result time shifted signal is x1x2 ?

Comment: I don't have any idea about the signals sources and the system, so I can't give an honest answer about the Shifted strain and shifted temperature. I can only say that the normalization is one technique among many others to remove biases and scale similarly. You may also want to try to remove trend, seasonality, etc (see Trend-Seasonality decomposition, I think it was implemented in statmodels package).

Comment: Thanks, but the result x1x2, is the shifted temperature ? or the shifted strain ?

Comment: No, I only plotted the ACF and the signals that you've claimed that you see incorrectly (in your question). As I explained, to extract the exact shift may be more complicated. For this case you can use a peak detector, take the first peak and use the index of the peak as the number of timesteps that are included in the shift. Then, take the *timestamps* column and calculate the shift in real time (seconds/ms/etc).

Comment: Should I make another question and you make an answer related to the calculation of time shift ? :)

Comment: No, its not about that - I gave here a comment about the calculation. I will shortly add it as an edit. But the main message is that you should research this subject a little to have a grasp on that issue.

Comment: mr_mo, should I do FFT and get the max peak ? that's what I think about

Comment: How would I transform the detected peak into time stamp ? can you show some pseudo code, assuming I got the maximum peak ?

Comment: After calculating the time shift, how would I shift the temperature signals using it ?

Comment: `delta_index = argmax(...); delta_time = timestamps[delta_index] - timestamps[0] #assuming timestamps is a datetime64 numpy array that can be easily obtained from pandas; sifted_signal = signal[delta_index:] #assuming signal is 1d nparray;`. Note that the new shifted signal is shorter.

Comment: I think you meant shifted_signal = signal[delta_time:]

Comment: It depends on what is the object type and how it is index. Using numpy, I meant `delta_index`, **not** `delta_time`.

Comment: I assumed that this is in your interest.

Comment: Can you look at the edited post and review it please ?

Comment: If the new shifted signal is shorted, how would I use it to plot it with Strain ? because I need actually to calculate the time delay between strain and temperature and use that signal again against the strain sensor

Comment: would you help me with that question ? it's related to your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443511/cut-two-signals-in-numpy