# Recover the time shift from nympy.correlate result in Python

Tags: python, numpy, cross-correlation

This is not a duplicate question since [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52367241/11748994) only explain how to plot the cross-correlation function and do not explain how you can get the time difference.
Given a sin signal and shifted version, we should be able to get the time delay between them.
I have created a sin signal and shifted it by `t_d=0.05`. The following is my code and its output:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fs = 1000
x = np.linspace(0, 1, fs)
f = 5
t_shift = 0.05
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*x)
y_shifted = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*(x-t_shift))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, x, y_shifted)
plt.show()
```

[image]

By normalizing signals and applying `numpy.correlate` we get the following:

```
y_norm = (y-y.mean())/y.std()
y_shifted_norm = (y_shifted - y_shifted.mean())/y_shifted.std()
cc = np.correlate(y_norm, y_shifted_norm, 'full')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(len(cc)), cc)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Question**
From the indices of cross-correlation function, how can I get `t_shift=0.05`?

Answer (score 1):

@Sepide. It seems to me as if you are trying to maximise the correlation between the signal `y` and a shifted version of `y_shifted`. This might be accomplished using `np.correlate()` but it seems nontrivial indeed to recover the time shifts in the signals. In the solution below I manually shift the time series and compute the correlation coefficient using `np.corrcoef`. As soon as this Pearson correlation coefficient equals 1, the  two signals are aligned.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Setting
fs = 1000
x = np.linspace(0, 1, fs)
f = 5
t_shift = 0.05
t_step = 1/fs

# Data
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*x)
y_shifted = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*(x-t_shift))

# Compute correlation
MaxTimeShift = 200
CorrelationList = np.empty((MaxTimeShift,1));
CorrelationList[:] = np.NaN
# Compute correlation for various shifts
for iter in range(MaxTimeShift):
    CorrelationList[iter] = np.corrcoef( y[0:801].T, y_shifted[iter:(801+iter)].T)[0,1]

# Plot 1
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, y, x, y_shifted)
plt.show()

# Plot 2
plt.figure(2)
ShiftList = t_step*np.arange(MaxTimeShift)
plt.plot(ShiftList, CorrelationList)
plt.title("Correlation coefficient")
plt.show()

print("The time shift between the signals is: ", ShiftList[np.argmax(CorrelationList)])
```

Comment: what would you get as the time shift value, can you print out some of the out put of your code for different time shifts?

Comment: @sepide. The time shift is printed out in the last print statement. For the given example, it is 0.05 (thus equal to t_shift)